# Select items from list

Tags: algorithm, vba, excel, combinations

Problem:

There are N Soccer players in the format below and the sheet will spit out every 11-player combination of the players.

Each 11-player line-up must follow the constraints below.

It should be able to select players as 'core' meaning that they will appear in 100% of the output line-ups.

Input:

```
  A               B       C        D                 E
Name          Position  Team     Salary     Core Player? 1="Yes",0="No"
Darron Gibson   M        EVE    6500000              0
Riyad Mahrez    M        LEI    11700000             0
Andrej Kramaric F        LEI    6900000              0
Sadio Mané      M        SOT    12600000             0
Victor Anichebe F        WBA    5300000              1
Serge Gnabry    M        WBA    6300000              0
Dimitri Payet   M        WHM    13500000             0
Juan Mata       M        MUN    10700000             0
  .
  .
  .so on there is list of players
```

Constraints for each team:

```
Maximum Salary  100000000   Allowed per team

'These are the maximum and minimum no. of players for a position per team   
Position    Min   Max   
  G          1    1
  D          3    4
  M          3    5
  F          1    3

'there can be maximum no. of four players from a single team
' e.g. MUN (manchester united)          
Maximum Number of Players from one team     4   
Total number of players     11            'Total no. of players per team
```

Output Example:

```
    Player 1    Player 2    Player 3    Player 4    Player 5    Player 6    Player 7    Player 8    Player 9    Player 10   Player 11
    Player 1    Player 2    Player 3    Player 4    Player 5    Player 6    Player 7    Player 8    Player 9    Player 10   Player 12
    Player 1    Player 2    Player 3    Player 4    Player 5    Player 6    Player 7    Player 8    Player 9    Player 10   Player 13
    Player 1    Player 2    Player 3    Player 4    Player 5    Player 6    Player 7    Player 8    Player 9    Player 10   Player 14
.
.
.
.

'Update: Players can be repeated in another teams but no match for full line up is allowed 

 Like this is not allowed

Player 1    Player 2    Player 3    Player 4    Player 5    Player 6    Player 7    Player 8    Player 9    Player 10   Player 11
Player 1    Player 3    Player 2    Player 5    Player 4    Player 6    Player 7    Player 8    Player 9    Player 10   Player 11
```

[Attached File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sz2gnnr8dzjfbld/Permutations.xlsm?dl=0)

My idea was to first place them and then check for constraints as the order in which they are selected doesn't matters and make them correct until the conditions are satisfied but this getting complex on every stage.

What I've tried (Not complete):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Teams()
Dim wi, wo, wt, ws As Worksheet
Dim i, j, l, d, m, ct, c, a, b, r As Long
Dim TotalG, TotalD, TotalM, TotalF, TotalSal, Sal, SalLeft, MaxTeam As Long
Dim Team, Pos, Name As String
Dim FinalRowI, FinalRowO As Long
Dim Drng As Range
Dim Mrng As Range

Set wi = Sheet1
Set wo = Sheet2
Set wt = Sheet3
Set ws = Sheet4

FinalRowI = wi.Range("A900000").End(xlUp).Row

TotalG = 0
TotalD = 0
TotalM = 0
TotalF = 0
Sal = 0
SalLeft = 0
TotalSal = wi.Range("H14").Value

    For i = 2 To FinalRowI

        Name = Trim(wi.Range("A" & i).Text)
        Pos = Trim(wi.Range("B" & i).Text)
        Team = Trim(wi.Range("C" & i).Text)
        Sal = wi.Range("D" & i).Value

        Select Case Pos

        Case "G"
            TotalG = TotalG + 1

        Case "D"
            TotalD = TotalD + 1

        Case "M"
            TotalM = TotalM + 1

        Case "F"
            TotalF = TotalF + 1

        Case Else
        End Select
    Next i

    MaxTeam = (WorksheetFunction.Min(CInt(TotalD), CInt(TotalM))) / 3

    MaxTeam = (WorksheetFunction.Min(CInt(MaxTeam), CInt(TotalG), CInt(TotalF)))

    MsgBox "MaxTeam " & MaxTeam
    MsgBox "G " & TotalG
    MsgBox "D " & TotalD
    MsgBox "M " & TotalM
    MsgBox "F " & TotalF

        m = 0
        d = 0
        c = 1
        ct = 1
        a = 1
        r = 1

        l = 3
        b = 6

        'Place all the Min Goalkeepers,Forwards, Mid, Defenders
        For i = 2 To FinalRowI

            Name = Trim(wi.Range("A" & i).Text)
            Pos = Trim(wi.Range("B" & i).Text)
            Team = Trim(wi.Range("C" & i).Text)
            Sal = wi.Range("D" & i).Value

            Select Case Pos

            Case "G"

                If ct <= MaxTeam Then
                    wo.Range("A" & ct) = Name
                    wt.Range("A" & ct) = Team
                    ws.Range("A" & ct) = Sal
                    ct = ct + 1
                Else: End If

            Case "D"

                If d <= 3 * MaxTeam And r <= MaxTeam Then
                    wo.Cells(r, l) = Name
                    wt.Cells(r, l) = Team
                    ws.Cells(r, l) = Sal
                        d = d + 1
                        If d Mod 3 = 0 Then
                            r = r + 1
                            l = 3
                        Else
                            l = l + 1
                        End If
                Else: End If

            Case "M"

                If m <= 3 * MaxTeam And a <= MaxTeam Then
                    wo.Cells(a, b) = Name
                    wt.Cells(a, b) = Team
                    ws.Cells(a, b) = Sal
                    m = m + 1
                        If m Mod 3 = 0 Then
                            a = a + 1
                            b = 6
                        Else
                            b = b + 1
                        End If
                Else: End If

            Case "F"

                If c <= MaxTeam Then
                    wo.Range("B" & c) = Name
                    wt.Range("B" & c) = Team
                    ws.Range("B" & c) = Sal
                    c = c + 1
                Else: End If

            Case Else
            End Select
        Next i

     Set Drng = wo.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(MaxTeam, 5))
     Set Mrng = wo.Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(MaxTeam, 8))

        m = 8
        d = 8
        c = 0
        ct = 0
        a = 1
        b = 1

        l = 3
        b = 6

'For Rest of three Places
    For i = 2 To FinalRow

        Name = Trim(wi.Range("A" & i).Text)
        Pos = Trim(wi.Range("B" & i).Text)
        Team = Trim(wi.Range("C" & i).Text)
        Sal = wi.Range("D" & i).Value

        Select Case Pos

        Case "G"

        Case "D"
            For Each c In Drng

            Next j

        Case "M"

        Case "F"

        Case Else
        End Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You have several compile errors that need to be fixed. Your code only outputs 8 columns instead of 11 (which is the minimum of all positions), therefore you need to add 3 more players. Your sample download file has none marked as 'Core', but I don't understand your comment above that 'Core' will appear in all lineups - does that mean each row will have one or more 'Cores'?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Thanks yes it has errors because it's not completed yet as I am pretty confused on how to proceed after placing the minimum required players in team. `Core` means that player has the highest priority in getting selected with respect to non core players and it can take only two values 1 and 0 so all the core players must be placed in team

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Think you can help me ? or atleast guide me on how to tackle this problem ?

Comment: I will take a look at your code and see if I can assist. But first, I want to be 100% accurate understanding what you are trying to do. You say '...spit out every 11-player combination of the players', do you have any idea how many combinations that would be?!?!  Try this webiste and see if you really mean that: http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/combinations-permutations.aspx

Comment: Thanks for looking at it so maximum possible teams according to the constraints can only be minimum of `=MIN(TotalGoalkeepers ,(Total Defenders/3),(TotalMidField PLayers/3),TotalForwards)` because those are the minimum requiremnts to forma a team there are other contraints also like Total Salary allowed per team and maximum nuber of players selected from a Team etc.

Comment: No Player should be repeated in any other team. That is every team has unique players depending on their name

Comment: You have 341 players, which divided by 11 makes 31 teams exactly. Yet you have 33 Goalies, thus the constraint of only 1 per team will result in 2 players that can't be assigned to a team, thus less than 31 teams? OK?

Comment: Yes also each team must have atleast 3 defenders and atleast 3 Midfield Players and atleast 1 Forward

Comment: The code you have can be adapted to fix the issue, but you will need to use some column on the 'Input' sheet to keep track if you already used that player in earlier code (you spin thru all names once to get 8 players, then need to get 3 more). I decided to try a very different approach where I randomly pick player names based on position, but that was just me playing around -- and it worked.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Can you please share your code even if it's incomplete now it will help me? I thought of randomly choosing players from list but I thought that would be more complex.

Comment: I placed my version in dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/79f83npagzepnr7/Permutations_REV.xlsm?dl=0 with a sheet named 'Notes', plus comments in the code.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Thank you very much ! Just one question does this have the abilty to select the core players first ? I mean the core players must be placed in any one team. I think this works as expected why don't you post your code as an answer I'll mark this is as one.

Comment: I updated the Excel WB in Dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/79f83npagzepnr7/Permutations_REV.xlsm?dl=0 I will post as an answer once I'm sure it is OK with you. Yes, it selects CORE players first, and checks limits. However two issues remain. (1) If limit exceeded, team is not adjusted to correct; (2) It's possible to reach the end, yet still have enough players to make another team if adjustments (substitution) were made to some prior team (i.e. earlier team has 3 midfielders, but now none available). What do you want to do?

Comment: I think I can implement to check limits and make changes accordingly. Sorry I didn't understand the second point

Comment: Re 2nd point: created 30 full teams, but at the end remaining G = 4, Fwd = 13, Mid = 6, but Def = 0. So need Def for next team. But 24 of the teams have 4 defenders. Maybe a logic change is necessary to either assign fewer defenders earlier, or to adjust the earlier team to take away a defender and add another position?

Comment: What if I say that players can be repeated in other teams but no full lineup team should match Please see the changed output format

Comment: Here's an idea... if the above situation happens, then walk backwards thru the completed teams, removing excess position players that we need now and substitute with a position where we have excess players?

Comment: Would you elaborate more on core players: 1) how many core players by position are in the entire pool of players?. 2) What's is the minimum\maximum number of core players by position in a team?.

Comment: Sure core player is indicated by digit 1 meaning that the player will have to be placed in 100% of the lineups.

Comment: so it's then one core player per position , except for goalkeeper (i.e. one core player for D, one for M and one for F and they must be in all teams) it's the above correct?

Comment: Use Excel's solver. http://superuser.com/questions/362349/excel-formula-needed/362350#362350

Comment: @EEM it's not necessary that the person has to choose any player as core player but when they do the player must be in 100% of the lineup. Also the player will not choose more than 1 goalkeeper as core since maximum no. of goalkeepers per team is 1 so selecting 2 goalkeepers as core will result in 0 team formation. Same goes with other position players as well.

Comment: @brettdj I thought of using that tool initially but I don't think it can handle so many constraints can it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have placed a new version in Dropbox (as of 12/30/2015 @ 7:00pm EST)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dvobwcpctolk18y/Permutations_REV3.xlsm?dl=0

** NOTE!! The code below is not complete due to size limitation!! I had to delete 7,000+ characters, so you will need to use the Dropbox code.

Please be aware that I added several new sheets to explain the process:
'Math' is used to indicate how many combinations of teams are permitted.
'Limits' tracks the names of teams the players come from.
'Original' is your original 'Input' sheet - easier to copy/paste for testing.

This solution tries to maximize the number of teams by using various combinations of team  positions and player availability.

It was my understanding that 'CORE' players were to be selected first, but were not duplicated across teams. If that is incorrect, I can adjust.

The following is the code that is used, but I suggest that you grab the Dropbox version:

```
Option Explicit

Dim WSi, WSo, WSt, WSs, WSl, WSm As Worksheet
Dim iGLow   As Integer
Dim iGHigh  As Integer
Dim iDLow   As Integer
Dim iDHigh  As Integer
Dim iMLow   As Integer
Dim iMHigh  As Integer
Dim iFLow   As Integer
Dim iFHigh  As Integer
Dim iCol    As Integer
Dim iGoalies, iMidfield, iForward, iDefense As Integer
Dim iGoaliesA, iMidfieldA, iForwardA, iDefenseA As Integer
Dim iCoreG, iCoreD, iCoreF, iCoreM As Integer
Dim iPlayers    As Integer
Dim iTeams      As Integer
Dim iRow        As Integer
Dim iTeamL      As Integer
Dim FSW         As Boolean
Dim FinalRowI   As Long
Dim lMaxSal     As Long
Dim iTeamRow    As Integer
Dim iGMin, IGMax   As Integer
Dim iDMin, IDMax   As Integer
Dim iFMin, IFMax   As Integer
Dim iMMin, IMMax   As Integer
Dim sCores      As String
Const cGoal = 13
Const cFwd = 15
Const cFwd2 = 18
Const cDef = 14
Const cDef2 = 17
Const cMid = 16
Const cMid2 = 19
Const cGA = 22
Const cDA = 23
Const cFA = 24
Const cMA = 25
Const cTTL = 20

Sub Teams()
Dim i   As Integer
Dim iT  As Integer
Dim i2  As Integer
Dim iGOAL, iFWD, iMID, iDEF As Integer

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap

    FSW = True

    If HouseKeeping = False Then
        MsgBox "Due to problems described earlier, this program will halt now. Please correct all problems.", vbOKOnly, "Program Halt"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    WSi.Activate

    For iTeamRow = 2 To iTeams + 1
        DoEvents
        iCol = 1            ' Initialize the Output Column number starting position
        sCores = ""         ' Use this to track CORE players per team

        iGOAL = 0: iFWD = 0: iMID = 0: iDEF = 0

        If iTeamRow Mod 10 = 0 Then
            If ArrangeInputList = True Then
                MsgBox "Problem with number of players by position."
            End If
        End If

        If iGoaliesA > 0 Then
            iRow = FindAnyRow("G", iGLow, iGHigh)
            If iRow = 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Unable to make any more teams."
                WSo.Rows(iTeamRow).Delete
                GoTo Finish_Up
            End If
            iGoaliesA = iGoaliesA - 1       ' Decrease count of available by position...
            iGOAL = iGOAL + 1
        Else
            Debug.Print "Bail out!"
            GoTo Finish_Up
        End If

        For i = 1 To WSm.Cells(2 + iTeamRow, cDef) + WSm.Cells(2 + iTeamRow, cDef2)
            iCol = iCol + 1
            iRow = FindAnyRow("D", iDLow, iDHigh)
            If iRow = 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Unable to make any more teams."
                WSo.Rows(iTeamRow).Delete
                GoTo Finish_Up
            End If
            iDefenseA = iDefenseA - 1      ' Decrease count of available by position...
            iDEF = iDEF + 1
        Next i

        For i = 1 To WSm.Cells(2 + iTeamRow, cFwd) + WSm.Cells(2 + iTeamRow, cFwd2)
            iCol = iCol + 1
            iRow = FindAnyRow("F", iFLow, iFHigh)
            If iRow = 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Unable to make any more teams."
                WSo.Rows(iTeamRow).Delete
                GoTo Finish_Up
            End If
            iForwardA = iForwardA - 1      ' Decrease count of available by position...
            iFWD = iFWD + 1
        Next i

        For i = 1 To WSm.Cells(2 + iTeamRow, cMid) + WSm.Cells(2 + iTeamRow, cMid2)
            iCol = iCol + 1
            iRow = FindAnyRow("M", iMLow, iMHigh)
            If iRow = 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Unable to make any more teams."
                WSo.Rows(iTeamRow).Delete
                WSt.Rows(iTeamRow).Delete
                WSs.Rows(iTeamRow).Delete
                GoTo Finish_Up
            End If
            iMidfieldA = iMidfieldA - 1      ' Decrease count of available by position...
            iMID = iMID + 1
        Next i

        ' Save Count by Position
        WSo.Cells(iTeamRow, 12) = iGOAL
        WSo.Cells(iTeamRow, 13) = iFWD
        WSo.Cells(iTeamRow, 14) = iDEF
        WSo.Cells(iTeamRow, 15) = iMID

        If (iGOAL <> 1) Or (iFWD > 3) Or (iMID > 5) Or (iDEF > 4) Then
            Debug.Print "Team composition exceeds limits: " & vbCrLf & _
            "Goalies = " & iGOAL & vbTab & "Forwards = " & iFWD & vbTab & "Midfielders = " & iMID & vbTab & "Defenders = " & iDEF
            MsgBox "Team composition exceeds limits: " & vbCrLf & _
            "Goalies = " & iGOAL & vbTab & "Forwards = " & iFWD & vbTab & "Midfielders = " & iMID & vbTab & "Defenders = " & iDEF
        End If
        If (iGOAL + iFWD + iMID + iDEF <> 11) Then
            Debug.Print "Team composition not enough players limits: " & vbCrLf & _
            "Goalies = " & iGOAL & vbTab & "Forwards = " & iFWD & vbTab & "Midfielders = " & iMID & vbTab & "Defenders = " & iDEF
            MsgBox "Team composition exceeds limits: " & vbCrLf & _
            "Goalies = " & iGOAL & vbTab & "Forwards = " & iFWD & vbTab & "Midfielders = " & iMID & vbTab & "Defenders = " & iDEF
        End If

        DoEvents
    Next iTeamRow


Finish_Up:

    WSt.Activate
    Range("M2").Select
    ActiveCell = "=COUNTIF($A2:$K2,M$1)"        '"=SUM(RC[-11]:RC[-1])"
    Range("M2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M2:AA" & Int(iTeams)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ' Add Conditional Formatting to turn team count to yellow if > 4 players
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=AND(OR(M2>4),M2<>"""")"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("M2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M2:Z31").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("Q3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Audit_Checks:

Dim sPlayer1    As String
Dim sPlayer2    As String
Dim sPosition   As String
Dim iRow1       As Integer
Dim iRow2       As Integer
Dim Rng1        As Range
Dim Rng2        As Range
Dim rCell       As Range
Dim iCol1       As Integer
Dim iCol2       As Integer
Dim iC1         As Integer
Dim iR1         As Integer
Dim sTeam       As String

    If WSs.Cells(iTeamRow, 12) > lMaxSal Then
        Debug.Print "Team Salary = " & WSs.Cells(iTeamRow, 12)
        MsgBox "Team Salary of: " & WSs.Cells(iRow, 12) & " exceeds Limit of: " & lMaxSal
    End If

    ' Find first team with > 4 players from same team...
    For Each rCell In WSt.Range("M2:AD" & iTeams + 1).Cells
        If rCell.Value > 4 Then
            'firstValue = rCell.Value
            iC1 = rCell.Column
            iR1 = rCell.Row
            For i = 2 To iTeams         ' Find a row with less than 4 playes for this team...
                If WSt.Cells(i, iC1) < 4 Then        ' If < 4, then we have a swap!
                    iRow2 = i
                    Debug.Print "Team #" & i - 1; " has only " & WSt.Cells(i, iC1) & " players from Team '" & WSt.Cells(1, iC1) & "'"
                    sTeam = WSt.Cells(1, iC1)
                    ' Now find a player to swap (must be same position also)
                    For i2 = 2 To 11
                        If WSt.Cells(iR1, i2) = WSt.Cells(1, iC1) Then
                            iRow1 = iR1
                            iCol1 = i2
                            sPlayer1 = WSo.Cells(iR1, i2)                 ' Get Players name & position
                            sPosition = Right(sPlayer1, 3)
                            sPlayer1 = Left(sPlayer1, Len(sPlayer1) - 4)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next i2
                    ' Now we need to find same position in the other team
                    ' iRow2 contains Target Row
                    For i2 = 2 To 11
                        If InStr(1, WSo.Cells(iRow2, i2), sPosition) > 0 And WSt.Cells(iRow2, i2) <> sTeam Then
                            iCol2 = i2
                            sPlayer2 = WSo.Cells(iRow2, i2)
                            sPlayer2 = Left(sPlayer2, Len(sPlayer2) - 4)

                            Set Rng1 = WSo.Cells(iRow1, iCol1)
                            Set Rng2 = WSo.Cells(iRow2, iCol2)

                            If SwapPlayers(sPlayer1, Rng1, sPlayer2, Rng2) = False Then
                                MsgBox "Failed to swap players: " & sPlayer1 & " with " & sPlayer2
                            End If
                            GoTo Audit_Checks
                        End If
                    Next i2
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next

End_Of_Time:

    Debug.Print "----------------END OF TEAMS---------------------"
    Debug.Print "Remaining: " & vbCrLf & _
                "Goalies  : " & iGoaliesA & vbTab & "(Need 1)" & vbCrLf & _
                "Forwards : " & iForwardA & vbTab & "(Need 1)" & vbCrLf & _
                "Defense  : " & iDefenseA & vbTab & "(Need 3)" & vbCrLf & _
                "Midfield : " & iMidfieldA & vbTab & "(Need 3)" & vbCrLf

    Exit Sub

Error_Trap:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "In: Teams"
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "In: Teams"
    Resume

End Sub

Function FindAnyRow(sPosition As String, iLow As Integer, iHigh As Integer) As Integer
' This function will receive the low and high row number for players by a position
' it will generate a random row number within that range, and if player not
' previously selected (X in 'selected' column), then will use that row #.
' As more players are taken from a range, the random number may spend too much time
' trying to find an unselected player in that range. If so, re-sort the list to exclude
' players that have already been selected.

Dim i       As Integer
Dim iTries  As Integer
Dim iRow    As Integer
Dim FindRow     As Range
Dim iCLow       As Integer
Dim iTaken      As Integer

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap

    'Debug.Print "FindAnyRow: Pos=" & sPosition & vbTab & iLow & vbTab & iHigh

    If iHigh - iLow < 0 Then
        Debug.Print "How is this going to work?" & vbTab & iLow & vbTab & iHigh
        FindAnyRow = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' First let's check if we have a CORE player for this position
    ' Future change: once all core players have been assigned, bypass this code...
    iCLow = iLow    ' Set low limit of rows to search for CORE
    Do
        DoEvents

        ' Having problems with 'Find' logic, so just use the K.I.S.S. method for now!
        For iRow = iCLow To iHigh
            If WSi.Range("E" & iRow) = 1 Then
                If InStr(1, sCores, WSi.Range("A" & iRow) & ",") = 0 Then
                    sCores = sCores & WSi.Range("A" & iRow) & ","        ' Add player to this team
                    FindAnyRow = iRow           ' Return the row #
                    'Debug.Print "Found CORE '" & sPosition & "' in row: " & iRow
                    WSo.Cells(iTeamRow, iCol) = WSi.Range("A" & iRow) & " (" & sPosition & ")"
                    WSt.Cells(iTeamRow, iCol) = WSi.Range("C" & iRow)
                    WSs.Cells(iTeamRow, iCol) = WSi.Range("D" & iRow)
                    ' If a CORE player - never mark as SELECTED. Thus will appear in every team
                    'WSi.Range("F" & iRow) = "X"
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next iRow
        Exit Do
    Loop

    ' Didn't find a CORE player, so let's find any player for this position!
    iTries = 0
    Do
        DoEvents
        iTries = iTries + 1         ' Count # times we have tried to find available player.
        If iTries > 21 Then         ' If more than 5, resort the list!
            ' ONE time during testing, the list was re-sorted, but then still failed to find a player.
            ' Just in case....
            iTaken = 0
            If iHigh - iLow <= 2 Then
                For i = iLow To iHigh
                    If WSi.Range("E" & i) = 1 Or WSi.Range("F" & iRow) <> "X" Then
                        iTaken = iTaken + 1
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
            If iTaken >= iHigh - iLow Then
                ' We have reached the limit on player combinations
                FindAnyRow = 0
                Exit Function
            Else
                MsgBox "Random / resort not working!!"
            End If
        ElseIf iTries > 15 Then
            If ArrangeInputList = True Then
                Debug.Print "Problem with number of players by position."
                FindAnyRow = 0
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
        DoEvents
        iRow = Int((iHigh - iLow + 1) * Rnd + iLow)    ' Get random number between low & high row
        'Check if already selected
        If WSi.Range("F" & iRow) = " " And WSi.Range("E" & iRow) <> 1 Then
            FindAnyRow = iRow           ' Return the row #
            WSo.Cells(iTeamRow, iCol) = WSi.Range("A" & iRow) & " (" & sPosition & ")"
            WSt.Cells(iTeamRow, iCol) = WSi.Range("C" & iRow)
            WSs.Cells(iTeamRow, iCol) = WSi.Range("D" & iRow)
            ' Don't mark a CORE by accident
            If WSi.Range("E" & iRow) <> 1 Then
                WSi.Range("F" & iRow) = "X"
            Else
                'Debug.Print "Prevented marking player by mistake."
            End If
            Exit Do                  ' Exit the loop
        End If
    Loop

    Exit Function

Error_Trap:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "In: FindAnyRow"
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "In: FindAnyRow"
    Resume

End Function

Function ArrangeInputList() As Boolean
' Sort the list of players by 'selected' column, then by position.
Dim blnStop As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap
    blnStop = False
    WSi.Activate
    Columns("A:F").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F2:F342") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B342") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:F342")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ' Now get the starting row for each position.
    WSi.Activate
    ' Range of Defense...
    iDLow = Range("B:B").Find(What:="D", After:=Range("B1")).Row
    ' Range of Forwards...
    iFLow = Range("B:B").Find(What:="F", After:=Range("B1")).Row
    ' Range of Goalies...
    iGLow = Range("B:B").Find(What:="G", After:=Range("B1")).Row
    ' Range of Midfielders...
    iMLow = Range("B:B").Find(What:="M", After:=Range("B1")).Row

    ' Calculate the ending row per position. Note: Can't search for MAX because prior 'selected'
    ' will still appear at the bottom of the list!
    iDHigh = iFLow - 1
    iFHigh = iGLow - 1
    iGHigh = iMLow - 1

    ' The last group (Midfielders) needs some help!
    If FSW = True Then
        ' First time thru, this will be the last row for midfielders.
        FSW = False
        iMHigh = iPlayers
    Else
        ' Any other time thru, this will be the last row before a 'selected' flag.
        iMHigh = Range("F:F").Find(What:="X", After:=Range("F1")).Row
    End If

    ' Check validity
    If iGHigh < iGLow Then
        Debug.Print "WHAT>>>"
        blnStop = True
    End If
    If iDHigh < iDLow Then
        Debug.Print "WHAT>>>"
        blnStop = True
    End If
    If iFHigh < iFLow Then
        Debug.Print "WHAT>>>"
        blnStop = True
    End If
    If iMHigh < iMLow Then
        Debug.Print "WHAT>>>"
        blnStop = True
    End If


    ' Count new total # players by position...
    iDefense = iDHigh - iDLow + 1
    iForward = iFHigh - iFLow + 1
    iGoalies = iGHigh - iGLow + 1
    iMidfield = iMHigh - iMLow + 1

    ' Calculate new total # players AVAILABLE by position...
    iDefenseA = iDHigh - iDLow + 1
    iForwardA = iFHigh - iFLow + 1
    iGoaliesA = iGHigh - iGLow + 1
    iMidfieldA = iMHigh - iMLow + 1

'    Debug.Print "Goalies Avail:   " & iGoaliesA
'    Debug.Print "Defenders Avail: " & iDefenseA
'    Debug.Print "Forwards Avail:  " & iForwardA
'    Debug.Print "Midfielders Avail: " & iMidfieldA

    Exit Function

Error_Trap:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "In: ArrangeInputList"
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "In: ArrangeInputList"
    Resume

End Function

Function SwapPlayers(sName1 As String, iRng1 As Range, sName2 As String, iRng2 As Range) As Boolean
' This routine will remove the selected player from their prior team and swap with another player.
Dim i       As Integer
Dim iRow1    As Integer
Dim iCol1    As Integer
Dim iRow2    As Integer
Dim iCol2    As Integer
Dim FindRow     As Integer
Dim rFound      As Range
Dim sName       As String
Dim iLen        As Integer
Dim lSalary1    As Long
Dim lSalary2    As Long
Dim sTeam1      As String
Dim sTeam2      As String
Dim sN1         As String
Dim sN2         As String

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap

    Debug.Print iRng1.Address & vbTab & iRng1.Row & "/" & iRng1.Column
    Debug.Print iRng2.Address & vbTab & iRng2.Row & "/" & iRng2.Column

    ' Find first player
    With WSi
        Set rFound = .Range("A2:A" & FinalRowI).Find(What:=sName1, LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        iRow1 = rFound.Row
    Else
        ' Impossible?
        MsgBox "Unable to find player: " & sName1
    End If

    ' Find second player
    With WSi
        Set rFound = .Range("A2:A" & FinalRowI).Find(What:=sName2, LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        iRow2 = rFound.Row
    Else
        ' Impossible?
        MsgBox "Unable to find player: " & sName1
    End If

    ' Get Salary and Team names
    sTeam1 = WSi.Cells(iRow1, 3)
    sTeam2 = WSi.Cells(iRow2, 3)
    lSalary1 = WSi.Cells(iRow1, 4)
    lSalary2 = WSi.Cells(iRow2, 4)
    sN1 = WSo.Cells(iRng1.Row, iRng1.Column)
    sN2 = WSo.Cells(iRng2.Row, iRng2.Column)

    ' Make the swap
    Debug.Print "Swap: " & sName1 & vbTab & sTeam1 & vbTab & lSalary1 & vbTab & "in RC:" & ""
    Debug.Print "With: " & sName2 & vbTab & sTeam2 & vbTab & lSalary2 & vbTab & "in RC:" & ""
    'Debug.Print WSo.Cells(iRng1.Row, iRng1.Column) & vbTab & WSt.Cells(iRng1.Row, iRng1.Column) & vbTab & WSs.Cells(iRng1.Row, iRng1.Column)
    'Debug.Print WSo.Cells(iRng2.Row, iRng2.Column) & vbTab & WSt.Cells(iRng2.Row, iRng2.Column) & vbTab & WSs.Cells(iRng2.Row, iRng2.Column)

    WSo.Cells(iRng1.Row, iRng1.Column) = sN2
    WSo.Cells(iRng2.Row, iRng2.Column) = sN1

    WSt.Cells(iRng1.Row, iRng1.Column) = sTeam2
    WSt.Cells(iRng2.Row, iRng2.Column) = sTeam1

    WSs.Cells(iRng1.Row, iRng1.Column) = lSalary2
    WSs.Cells(iRng2.Row, iRng2.Column) = lSalary1

    SwapPlayers = True

    Exit Function

Error_Trap:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "In: SwapPlayer"
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "In: SwapPlayer"
    Exit Function

End Function

Function HouseKeeping() As Boolean
' General setup code to:
' - Clear sheet contents
' - Get Team Names
' - Calculate makeup of teams by positions (Math worksheet)

Dim i           As Integer
Dim i2          As Integer
Dim iSum        As Integer
Dim blnFail     As Boolean
Dim iHalf       As Integer
Dim iCtr        As Integer
Dim bSkipBalance    As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap

    blnFail = False    ' Set default to 'FAIL' mode - if good exit, change to pass

    Set WSi = Sheet1
    Set WSo = Sheet2
    Set WSt = Sheet3
    Set WSs = Sheet4
    Set WSl = Sheet5
    Set WSm = Sheet8

    Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents
    Sheet3.Cells.ClearContents
    Sheet4.Cells.ClearContents
    Sheet5.Cells.ClearContents

    iGMin = WSi.Cells(17, 8):     IGMax = WSi.Cells(17, 9)
    iDMin = WSi.Cells(18, 8):     IDMax = WSi.Cells(18, 9)
    iFMin = WSi.Cells(19, 8):     IFMax = WSi.Cells(19, 9)
    iMMin = WSi.Cells(20, 8):     IMMax = WSi.Cells(20, 9)

    WSo.Cells(1, 1) = "Goalie"
    WSo.Cells(1, 2) = "2"
    WSo.Cells(1, 3) = "3"
    WSo.Cells(1, 4) = "4"
    WSo.Cells(1, 12) = "# G"
    WSo.Cells(1, 13) = "# D"
    WSo.Cells(1, 14) = "# F"
    WSo.Cells(1, 15) = "# M"

    ' Get last row, which is # Players +1
    FinalRowI = WSi.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    iPlayers = FinalRowI - 1

    ' Clear 'Selected' column - used to indicate a player has been assigned a team
    WSi.Activate
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = " "      ' need one space for sort to work properly
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F3:F" & FinalRowI).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ' Setup Math worksheet...
    WSm.Activate

    ' Count Players by position. Place in Math worksheet
    WSm.Cells(4, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Range("B2:B" & FinalRowI), "G")
    WSm.Cells(5, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Range("B2:B" & FinalRowI), "D")
    WSm.Cells(6, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Range("B2:B" & FinalRowI), "F")
    WSm.Cells(7, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Range("B2:B" & FinalRowI), "M")

    ' In theory, this is the max number of teams
    iTeams = FinalRowI / 11

    ' Do we have enough Goalies to make teams?
    If WSm.Cells(4, 4) < iTeams Then
        iTeams = WSm.Cells(4, 4)
    End If

    ' Get # Core players
    iCoreG = 0: iCoreD = 0: iCoreF = 0: iCoreM = 0:

    For i = 2 To FinalRowI
        If WSi.Cells(i, 5) = 1 Then
            If WSi.Cells(i, 2) = "G" Then
                iCoreG = iCoreG + 1
            ElseIf WSi.Cells(i, 2) = "D" Then
                iCoreD = iCoreD + 1
            ElseIf WSi.Cells(i, 2) = "F" Then
                iCoreF = iCoreF + 1
            ElseIf WSi.Cells(i, 2) = "M" Then
                iCoreM = iCoreM + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i


    ' Clear Map of team composition
    WSm.Range("L4:Y300").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents

    i = 0

    ' Loop as long as we can build a team....
    Do
        bSkipBalance = False

        i = i + 1
        WSm.Cells(3 + i, cTTL).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-7]:RC[-1])"    ' Add formula to sum count of players on team

        If iCoreG = 0 Then
            WSm.Cells(3 + i, cGA).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C-RC[-9]"     ' Goalie Remainder
        Else
            WSm.Cells(3 + i, cGA).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"            ' No limit on goalie
        End If

        If iCoreD = 0 Then
            WSm.Cells(3 + i, cDA).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C-RC[-9]-RC[-6]"                  ' Defender Remainder
        Else
            WSm.Cells(3 + i, cDA).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C-RC[-9]-RC[-6]+" & iCoreD        ' Defender Remainder
        End If

        If iCoreF = 0 Then
            WSm.Cells(3 + i, cFA).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C-RC[-9]-RC[-6]"                  ' Forward Remainder
        Else
            WSm.Cells(3 + i, cFA).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C-RC[-9]-RC[-6]+" & iCoreF        ' Forward Remainder
        End If

        If iCoreM = 0 Then
            WSm.Cells(3 + i, cMA).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C-RC[-9]-RC[-6]"                  ' Midfielder Remainder
        Else
            WSm.Cells(3 + i, cMA).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C-RC[-9]-RC[-6]+" & iCoreM        ' Midfielder Remainder

        End If

        WSm.Cells(3 + i, 12) = i        ' Set map of positions
        WSm.Cells(3 + i, cGoal) = 1
        WSm.Cells(3 + i, cDef) = 3
        WSm.Cells(3 + i, cFwd) = 1
        WSm.Cells(3 + i, cMid) = 3

        ' If we have Excess Defenders, use them (can ONLY use ONE more!!)
        If WSm.Cells(3 + i, 12) > WSm.Cells(3 + i, cDA) Then    ' was WSm.Cells(5, 9)
            WSm.Cells(3 + i, cDef2) = 0
        Else
            WSm.Cells(3 + i, cDef2) = 1
        End If
```

Comment: I think you are very close to the final output can we perform combinations from the output that we got keeping in mind the constraints. Please see the update output format.

Comment: During testing, I never encountered salary > $$$; code prevents > 4 players from same team, and conforms to the min-max by position; code also calculates and builds maximum number of teams that can be made, given # players per position; CORE players are selected first (but are unique across teams); if you have 1 CORE forward, is that same person supposed to appear on EVERY team?

Comment: Yes if a player is a core player then he must be appearing in every line up. Using this logic there wont be any two goalkeepers as core because then there wont be any possible teams same goes for forwards and other position players.

Comment: Btw when I ran the Teams macro so it gave me error : 1004    Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed
In: HouseKeeping

Comment: Clarity regarding CORE is certainly needed here because earlier you stated "I mean the core players must be placed in any one team." Note the "ONE TEAM" part. @EEM asked earlier how many core's were allowed, but I see no definition. Can you have 4 CORE defenders? If so, why list ANY other defenders because they will never be used? It would be helpful to know the line of code you get the error on and what you did to the data before the error. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake I am using excel 2013. In question above it's said the core players must be appearing in 100% of the lineups means in every team. E.g. if I choose a goalkeeper and a forward as core then they must be included in every team.

Comment: Placed a *final* version in Dropbox that handles CORE player(s). Code shown in the 'Answer' is not correct because I had to delete 7,000 characters to fit limitations of posting.

Comment: Yes core players can be duplicated if they meet then other criteria like max amount of allowed team salary and no. Of defenders etc.

Answer (score 4):

Consider an SQL solution which runs random iterations of the 11-player sequence and validates each iteration to meet all required conditions. MS Access, which works great with its Office sibling MS Excel can be a viable solution. Also, any RDMS can run below in a stored procedure. Below is the sequence of events and needed objects. Here is the [MS Access accdb app](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52743550/SoccerApp.accdb) empty of any picks for your testing.

**Table**

First, create a final table `SoccerPicks` to hold all 11 member teams which will grow over lifetime of app. It is used in append query called by VBA module below, inserting a successfully validated team record per each looped iteration.

**Cross Join Query**

Second, create a [randomized](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/rnd.php) [Cross Join Query](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) (returns all possible combinations of a choice set) but selects one player per 11 player tables and conditions the Positions (G, D, M, F) counts. In the `FROM` clause, the first four correspond to four core players and these individuals will show up on every team. Replicate their derived tables for more or remove and copy a randomized derived table as the other 7 are set up.

```
SELECT Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4, Player5, Player6, 
       Player7, Player8, Player9, Player10, Player11, 

       (t1.Salary + t2.Salary + t3.Salary + t4.Salary + t5.Salary + t6.Salary +
        t7.Salary + t8.Salary + t9.Salary + t10.Salary + t11.Salary) AS TeamSalary, 
       IIF(t1.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + IIF(t2.Position = 'G', 1, 0) +
       IIF(t3.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + IIF(t4.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + 
       IIF(t5.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + IIF(t6.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + 
       IIF(t7.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + IIF(t8.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + 
       IIF(t9.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + IIF(t10.Position = 'G', 1, 0) +
       IIF(t11.Position = 'G', 1, 0) AS GPosition, 

       IIF(t1.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + IIF(t2.Position = 'D', 1, 0) +
       IIF(t3.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + IIF(t4.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + 
       IIF(t5.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + IIF(t6.Position = 'D', 1, 0) +
       IIF(t7.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + IIF(t8.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + 
       IIF(t9.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + IIF(t10.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + 
       IIF(t11.Position = 'D', 1, 0) AS DPosition, 

       IIF(t1.Position = 'M', 1, 0) + IIF(t2.Position = 'M', 1, 0) +
       IIF(t3.Position = 'M', 1, 0) + IIF(t4.Position = 'M', 1, 0) +
       IIF(t5.Position = 'M', 1, 0) + IIF(t6.Position = 'M', 1, 0) +
       IIF(t7.Position = 'M', 1, 0) + IIF(t8.Position = 'M', 1, 0) + 
       IIF(t9.Position = 'M', 1, 0) + IIF(t10.Position = 'M', 1, 0) +
       IIF(t11.Position = 'M', 1, 0) AS MPosition, 

       IIF(t1.Position = 'F', 1, 0) + IIF(t2.Position = 'F', 1, 0) +
       IIF(t3.Position = 'F', 1, 0) + IIF(t4.Position = 'F', 1, 0) +
       IIF(t5.Position = 'F', 1, 0) + IIF(t6.Position = 'F', 1, 0) +
       IIF(t7.Position = 'F', 1, 0) + IIF(t8.Position = 'F', 1, 0) + 
       IIF(t9.Position = 'F', 1, 0) + IIF(t10.Position = 'F', 1, 0) +
       IIF(t11.Position = 'F', 1, 0) AS FPosition

FROM 
    (SELECT PlayerName as Player1, Position, Team, Salary    
     FROM Soccer 
     WHERE [Core Player] = True AND
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM Soccer sub 
            WHERE sub.ID <= Soccer.ID  
            AND sub.[Core Player] = True 
            AND Soccer.[Core Player] = True) = 1)  AS t1, 

    (SELECT PlayerName as Player2, Position, Team, Salary
     FROM Soccer 
     WHERE [Core Player] = True AND
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM Soccer sub 
            WHERE sub.ID <= Soccer.ID  
            AND sub.[Core Player] = True 
            AND Soccer.[Core Player] = True) = 2)  AS t2, 

    (SELECT PlayerName as Player3, Position, Team, Salary    
     FROM Soccer  
     WHERE [Core Player] = True AND
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM Soccer sub 
            WHERE sub.ID <= Soccer.ID  
            AND sub.[Core Player] = True 
            AND Soccer.[Core Player] = True) = 3)  AS t3, 

    (SELECT PlayerName as Player4, Position, Team, Salary
     FROM Soccer 
     WHERE [Core Player] = True AND
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM Soccer sub 
            WHERE sub.ID <= Soccer.ID  
            AND sub.[Core Player] = True 
            AND Soccer.[Core Player] = True) = 4)  AS t4, 

    (SELECT TOP 1 PlayerName AS Player5, Position, Team, Salary 
     FROM Soccer ORDER BY Rnd(ID))  AS t5, 

    (SELECT TOP 1 PlayerName AS Player6, Position, Team, Salary 
     FROM Soccer ORDER BY Rnd(ID))  AS t6, 

    (SELECT TOP 1 PlayerName AS Player7, Position, Team, Salary 
     FROM Soccer ORDER BY Rnd(ID))  AS t7, 

    (SELECT TOP 1 PlayerName AS Player8, Position, Team, Salary 
     FROM Soccer ORDER BY Rnd(ID))  AS t8, 

    (SELECT TOP 1 PlayerName AS Player9, Position, Team, Salary 
     FROM Soccer ORDER BY Rnd(ID))  AS t9, 

    (SELECT TOP 1 PlayerName AS Player10, Position, Team, Salary
     FROM Soccer ORDER BY Rnd(ID))  AS t10,

    (SELECT TOP 1 PlayerName AS Player11, Position, Team, Salary 
     FROM Soccer ORDER BY Rnd(ID))  AS t11

WHERE 

   IIF(t1.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + IIF(t2.Position = 'G', 1, 0) +
   IIF(t3.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + IIF(t4.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + 
   IIF(t5.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + IIF(t6.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + 
   IIF(t7.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + IIF(t8.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + 
   IIF(t9.Position = 'G', 1, 0) + IIF(t10.Position = 'G', 1, 0) +
   IIF(t11.Position = 'G', 1, 0) = 1 

AND
   IIF(t1.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + IIF(t2.Position = 'D', 1, 0) +
   IIF(t3.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + IIF(t4.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + 
   IIF(t5.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + IIF(t6.Position = 'D', 1, 0) +
   IIF(t7.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + IIF(t8.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + 
   IIF(t9.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + IIF(t10.Position = 'D', 1, 0) + 
   IIF(t11.Position = 'D', 1, 0) BETWEEN 3 AND 4

AND 
   IIF(t1.Position = 'M', 1, 0) + IIF(t2.Position = 'M', 1, 0) +
   IIF(t3.Position = 'M', 1, 0) + IIF(t4.Position = 'M', 1, 0) +
   IIF(t5.Position = 'M', 1, 0) + IIF(t6.Position = 'M', 1, 0) +
   IIF(t7.Position = 'M', 1, 0) + IIF(t8.Position = 'M', 1, 0) + 
   IIF(t9.Position = 'M', 1, 0) + IIF(t10.Position = 'M', 1, 0) +
   IIF(t11.Position = 'M', 1, 0) BETWEEN 3 AND 5

AND
   IIF(t1.Position = 'F', 1, 0) + IIF(t2.Position = 'F', 1, 0) +
   IIF(t3.Position = 'F', 1, 0) + IIF(t4.Position = 'F', 1, 0) +
   IIF(t5.Position = 'F', 1, 0) + IIF(t6.Position = 'F', 1, 0) +
   IIF(t7.Position = 'F', 1, 0) + IIF(t8.Position = 'F', 1, 0) + 
   IIF(t9.Position = 'F', 1, 0) + IIF(t10.Position = 'F', 1, 0) +
   IIF(t11.Position = 'F', 1, 0) BETWEEN 1 AND 3

AND 
  (t1.Salary + t2.Salary + t3.Salary + t4.Salary + t5.Salary + t6.Salary + 
   t7.Salary + t8.Salary + t9.Salary + t10.Salary + t11.Salary) <= 100000000;
```

[image: Soccer Permutations Cross Join Query]

**VBA Module**

Next is the VBA module that runs an append and delete queries (to remove failed records that do not meet other constraints). Notice the `for` loop at 50 iterations. Increase as needed, knowing there is quite a bit of choice sets with 11 players. Iterations are needed because above query may return zero depending on that random draw and the `WHERE` logic conditioning. NOTE: First two delete queries require a union query to stack all players in first above query to better aggregate team counts, player counts, and team salary summation. See attached app.

```
Public Function IteratePicks()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim i As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb

    For i = 1 To 50
        db.Execute "INSERT INTO SoccerPicks SELECT * FROM SoccerTeamPicksQ", dbFailOnError

        ' DELETING TEAMS WITH DUPLICATE PLAYERS
        db.Execute "DELETE FROM SoccerPicks" _
                    & " WHERE SoccerPicks.ID IN" _
                    & " (SELECT ID" _
                    & "  FROM (SELECT SoccerPicksUnionQ.ID, SoccerPicksUnionQ.Player, Count(*) AS PlayerCount" _
                    & "       FROM SoccerPicksUnionQ " _
                    & "  GROUP BY SoccerPicksUnionQ.ID, SoccerPicksUnionQ.Player" _
                    & "  HAVING Count(*) > 1) AS dT);", dbFailOnError    

        ' DELETING TEAMS WITH TEAM PLAYER COUNT > 4
        db.Execute "DELETE FROM SoccerPicks" _
                    & " WHERE SoccerPicks.ID IN" _
                    & " (SELECT ID AS MaxID" _
                    & "  FROM (SELECT SoccerPicksUnionQ.ID, SoccerPicksUnionQ.Team, Count(*) AS TeamCount" _
                    & "       FROM SoccerPicksUnionQ" _
                    & "       GROUP BY SoccerPicksUnionQ.ID, SoccerPicksUnionQ.Team)  AS dT" _
                    & "  GROUP BY ID" _
                    & "  HAVING Max(TeamCount) >= 4);", dbFailOnError

        ' DELETING TEAMS WITH SAME PLAYERS (I.E. SAME SALARY)
        db.Execute "DELETE FROM SoccerPicks" _
                    & " WHERE ID IN" _
                    & " (SELECT ID AS MaxID" _
                    & "  FROM SoccerPicks" _
                    & "  WHERE TeamSalary IN" _
                    & "         (SELECT sub.TeamSalary" _
                    & "         FROM SoccerPicks sub" _
                    & "         WHERE sub.ID < SoccerPicks.ID));", dbFailOnError
    Next i

    Set db = Nothing


    MsgBox "Successfully completed!", vbInformation
End Function
```